# auto number of line in excel formula to prevent manual edit

Tags: excel

I have this function on each line:

```
=SUMIF(B1:B60000;A1;C1:C60000)
=SUMIF(B1:B60000;A2;C1:C60000)
=SUMIF(B1:B60000;A3;C1:C60000)
```

As you can see just A1, A2, A3,etc. are changing according to the same number of line (auto number of each line). 
Any idea how can I replace "A1, A2, A3, ..." in smarter way to prevent manual edit of this value on every cell on each line?

Comment: Use the `$` to lock a row or column, e.g. `A$1` instead of `A1` on the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for this. `$` in front of a column letter or row acts as an anchor so it does not change. So don't put a `$` in front of where you want to row to change.

```
=SUMIF($B$1:$B$60000;$A1;$C$1:$C$60000)
```

If you do not need to copy this formula along a row, you can use this:

```
=SUMIF(B$1:B$60000;A1;C$1:$C$60000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Type this in first row:

```
=SUMIF($B$1:$B$60000;A1;$C$1:$C$60000)
```

Then fill down the column or copy paste.

This makes all other range "absolute" (dont change when copy/paste to another place) but only `A1` is *relative*, so it changes relatively with copy/paste.